# DRY in Ruby - Is it okay to repeat a line of code?

Tags: ruby, dry

I am newbie to programming and ruby. I am using a method to identify who somebody's secret santa is. The method takes String and Integer arguments (first name or id). I have different code for String and Integer arguments. This results in repeating the same line of code for different arguments (secret = PERSONS[person[:santa]-1]).

My questions are two-fold:

1. Is this kind of repetition against DRY principles? Is there another way to avoid the repetition?
2. See that I initialized local_variable secret outside the iterator and use the iterator to pass to that variable. Is this the most efficient way of doing this? Can I just return a value from the iterator without initializing a local variable?

My code is below. Also, I am enclosing a sample hash of data (PERSONS) that I am running the code on.

```
 def who_is_secret_santa(first_name)
  secret = nil
  PERSONS.each do |person|
    if first_name.is_a? String
      if person[:first_name] == first_name
        secret = PERSONS[person[:santa]-1]
      end
    elsif first_name.is_a? Integer
      if person[:id] == first_name
        secret = PERSONS[person[:santa]-1]
      end
    else
      puts "Bad argument"
    end
  end
  puts "#{first_name}'s Secret Santa " + (secret ? "is #{secret[:first_name]}" : "not found")
end


[{:id=>1,
  :first_name=>"Luke",
  :last_name=>"Skywalker",
  :email=>"<luke@theforce.net>",
  :santa=>4},
 {:id=>2,
  :first_name=>"Leia",
  :last_name=>"Skywalker",
  :email=>"<leia@therebellion.org>",
  :santa=>7},
 {:id=>3,
  :first_name=>"Toula",
  :last_name=>"Portokalos",
  :email=>"<toula@manhunter.org>",
  :santa=>5},
 {:id=>4,
  :first_name=>"Gus",
  :last_name=>"Portokalos",
  :email=>"<gus@weareallfruit.net>",
  :santa=>2},
 {:id=>5,
  :first_name=>"Bruce",
  :last_name=>"Wayne",
  :email=>"<bruce@imbatman.com>",
  :santa=>3},
 {:id=>6,
  :first_name=>"Virgil",
  :last_name=>"Brigman",
  :email=>"<virgil@rigworkersunion.org>",
  :santa=>1},
 {:id=>7,
  :first_name=>"Lindsey",
  :last_name=>"Brigman",
  :email=>"<lindsey@iseealiens.net>",
  :santa=>6}]
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/05/better-algorithms.html

Comment: It's not about your particular code, but may  help you with the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to avoid repetition in this case by first checking for a "bad argument" and then afterwards selecting the correct person from the array.

For your second question, you are probably looking for the [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) iterator instead of the each. It will return all of the elements in your array that make the condition in the block passed to it true.

Below is some code. p will represent the person whose first_name was passed to the method.

```
def who_is_secret_santa(first_name)
  if ! ((first_name.is_a? String) || (first_name.is_a? Integer))
    puts "Bad argument"
  else
    p = (PERSONS.select do |person| person[:first_name] == first_name || person[:id] == first_name end)[0]
    puts "#{first_name}'s Secret Santa " + (p ? "is #{PERSONS[p[:santa]-1][:first_name]}" : "not found")
  end
end
```